# Sobrepor um video sobre um fundo, e adicionar um logo sobre um menu

Tags: html, css

Não estou conseguindo sobrepor um logo sobre um menu que criei no site,
e não estou conseguindo adicionar um vídeo em cima de uma imagem no site.
Alguém poderia me dar essa força?

Segue as img:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wp2D.jpg
eu queria pôr esse vídeo em cima dessa imagem de fundo.

sobre o logo :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LkBK.jpg

eu queria q fosse assim :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk9RZ.jpg

o meu código até o momento:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300|Lato:400,300,700);
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cuprum:400,400i,700,700i');
h1 {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #ff0000;
}

h2 {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #ffce0b;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.wrap {
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  background: #383838;
}

.header .menutop {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.header .menu {
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #202020;
}

.header .menu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.header .menu ul li {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 23px 0 0;
}

.header .menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 32px 0;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #eeeeee;
}

.header .menu ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: #b0fafd;
}

.slide {
  margin: 0;
}

.slide .fundo1 {
  margin: 0;
  width: 1583px;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  background: url(../images/fundo1.png);
}

.footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0px 0 0 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ababab;
  text-align: center;
  background: #484846;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 -30px 0 0;
  height: 500px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.row h1 {
  color: #53a062;
  font-family: Forte;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.row h2 {
  color: #c2945b;
  font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 48px;
}

.raw {
  margin: 0 -30px 0 0;
  height: 500px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.raw {
  margin: 0;
  width: 1583px;
  height: 500px;
  display: block;
  background: url(../images/fundo2.png);
}

.raw h1 {
  color: #b7d0ff;
  text-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur-radius color|none|initial|inherit;
  font-family: 'Cuprum', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 38px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Secure JOB</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.prefixed.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.theme.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="menutop">
    </div>
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="contato.html" title="CONTATO">CONTATO</a></li>
        <li><a href="faq.html" title="FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="vit.html" title="VITÓRIAS">VITÓRIAS</a></li>
        <li><a href="duo.html" title="DUOBOOST">DUOBOOST</a></li>
        <li><a href="elo.html" title="ELOBOOST">ELOBOOST</a></li>
        <li><a href="md10.html" title="MD10">FAQ</a></li>
        <li><a href="inicio.html" title="ÍNICIO">ÍNICIO</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section class="slide">
    <div class="fundo1">
      <img scr="images/fundo1.png" />
    </div>
  </section>


  <section class="conteudo">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="row">
        <h1 align="center">A ÚNICA COM SEGURANÇA</h1>
        <h2 align="center">PMD</h2>
        <p>Nós da SecureElobosting percebemos que muitos sites de ELOJOB tiveram seus dados vazados por hackers, muitos clientes tiveram seus emails vazados e consequentemente tiveram suas contas banidas do LEAGUE OF LEGENDS. Foi por isso que nós da SecureJob
          criamos esse sistema de segurança chamado PMD. Mas afinal, o que é a segurança PMD? PMD significa Pendrive – Messenger- Description. Usamos um messenger criptografado para troca de informações (planos PREMIUM e SJBOOST), pendrive para armazenar
          o MÍNIMO de suas informações, sem manter NADA online, Sendo assim, se um de nossos boosters ou administradores sofrerem ataques em seus computadores, nenhuma informação sua correrá riscos, tudo estará armazenado em um pendrive, sendo imediatamente
          deletado após a efetuação do seu elojob.</p>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="conteudofaq">
    <div class="raw">
      <br />
      <h1 align="center">COMO TER O SEU ELO DOS SONHOS EM POUCO TEMPO SEM TROLLS</h1>
    </div>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QN_FdiMItvA" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

  </section>


  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="wrap">
        <p align="left">© SecureElojob 201-2017 | TODOS OS DIREITOS RESERVADOS</p>
        <p>League of legends é uma marca registrada da Riot Games, Inc. Nós não somos de nenhuma forma afiliados, associados ou endossado pela Riot Games, Inc. Todos os direitos autoriais, marcas, imagens e marcas de serviço pertencem a seus respectivos
          proprietários.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: se eu entendi o que você quer em ambos os casos você consegue usando `background: url()`

Answer (score 0):

É isso?

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0;}
.menu{
display:block;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
line-height: 50px;
background: #333 url(https://s.imgur.com/images/imgur-logo.svg?1) no-repeat 20px 50%;
}
.menu li{
display:inline-block;
list-style:none;
text-transform:uppercase;
margin: 0 10px;
}
.menu li a{
color: #fff;
font-family: arial;
font-size: 12px;
text-decoration:none;
}
.menu li a:hover{
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
<li><a href="">item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```